# Debugging on Pycharm while using Anaconda Env

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda

I've changed interpreter to use an environment i've created on Anaconda. 
I used it to install tensorflow on Win10.

If I try to run a script everything works 
If I try to debug any script (even empty *.py file)
I'm getting:

```
  C:\Users\Barak\Anaconda3\envs\tfenv\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 54754 --file C:/Users/Barak/PycharmProjects/CV1/gg.py
pydev debugger: process 8588 is connecting


Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Please help me, it look like the debugger is not configured or something..help!!!

Thanks

Comment: Seems the same answer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649827/pycharm-debugger-cant-start-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005/50769555#50769555 applies here.

Comment: Seems the same answer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649827/pycharm-debugger-cant-start-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005/50769555#50769555 applies here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO` and `PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL=NO` environment variables to the corresponding run configuration. It should temporarily fix the problem. Meanwhile, please file a ticket in [PyCharms bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) with details about your environment (Python and `tensorflow` versions, `idea.log` file from **Help | Show Log in ...**).

Answer (score 0):

I think Pavel meant to try to add PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON with value 1, at least, this method worked for me in Pycharm

I had set the value for PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON for 1 [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpvYr.png)

Now i unfortunately have this square at my terminal output [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMjDr.png), BUT, its surely pretty better than a long misleading error message