# Pycharm debugger can't start: finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, anaconda

After reinstalling anaconda, I set up a new Pycharm project. When I debug one of my python scripts it get this error:

> pydev debugger: process 12636 is connecting 
>   Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

This only happens when I debug. Any advice?

For reference, these are the software versions I am currently using:

> Python version: 3.5
>   Pycharm version: 2017.3
>   Anaconda Navigator version:1.8.7

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Comment: Had the same issue. Solved it with the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326171/pycharm-4-0-3-crash-any-pyqt-program-wile-debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem as you Bob.

Here is my **workaround** (not a complete fix but it does the job) :

Copy/paste the entire sites-packages folder from the anaconda (or miniconda => works for me too) to the default python interpreter and switch to this default python.exe interpreter inside your project (Settings -> Project Interpreter).

For example overwrite the folder C:\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages to C:\Users\ *YOUR_ACCOUNT*\venv\Lib\site-packages

After that run AND debug modes are both available.

Hope this help !

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when running PyCharm debugger with code that includes following:

```
from pympler import muppy
all_objects=muppy.get_objects()  # this method causes pydev debugger exit
```

It was fine if execute the same piece of code through PyCharm in non-debug (Run) mode. Disabled the above code in debug mode, issue resolved.

Environment: PyCharm Community 2019.3, Anaconda 3, Python 3.7.3, pympler 0.7, Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

In my case, updating the pyqt4 package ([precompiled version](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above I've encountered this with a range of packages with pyCharm--usually closing and opening pyCharm fixes the issue (updating pyCharm version).

If that doesn't work, I methodically update all python packages.

Answer (score 0):

Same in version 2023.1.
It is a known bug (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54397/Debugger-crashes-when-breakpoint-is-inside-a-loop).
The workaround working in my case was adding the following environment variable:
[image]